# two sample test for large dataset

Tags: hypothesis-testing, large-data, two-sample

I want to perform two sample test on large dataset (in my case, each sample size is around one billion, and each data point is single real number). Which statistical test should I choose?

The null hypothesis is that two samples are from the same distribution, and alternative is that two samples are from different distribution. There is no prior knowledge of distribution, i.e. we know nothing about what kind of distribution these samples come from.

Each data point is suppose to be count, an simple example will be how many times a person visit a webpage. Each point is the data for a single user.

The assumption is that each point is sampled independently, i.e. each person behavior independently.

I am considering:

1. Kolgormorov-Smirnoff (KS) test
2. Mann-Whitney (MW) test
3. Mood test
4. Lepage-type (LP) test
5. Maximum mean discrepancy (MMD) test

Comment: It's impossible to reasonably suggest anything because  1. you don't indicate *what it is exactly you want to test for* (what are your null and alternative)? 2. What are your data? Counts? times? lengths? angles? ... 3. That's a pretty big sample size; generally random variation isn't the prime issue any more; bias is. What problem are you solving here? What's the test supposed to tell you that wouldn't already be obvious? 4. What would it be reasonable to assume? Random sampling (of what? why?) Independence? (why?)

Comment: The problem with these kinds of sample sizes is that nearly any test will tell you that, at quite low values of `alpha`, these samples are significantly different. As `n` increases, almost any (small) deviation becomes significant at any desired significance level `alpha`. Generally, I'd plot some distributions or print some statistics, and make a more economic interpretation first (i.e. the difference may be 'small'). Formal testing should come second if required.